# check attribute with value 0 exists or not returns false though it should return true as it exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to check if an attribute is in a json file or not but the attribute has a value of 0 so the following

```
status.bytes_read
```

returns false though it should return true as it exists
what is the best way of handling this case?

Comment: I'd use `status.bytes_read != null`, which will cover both `null` and `undefined`. Or you could use `if ("bytes_read" in status)`.